# Dgrid-OnDemandGrid Virtualscrolling

Tags: dgrid

I am using Dgrid OndemandGrid with Jsonrest store.On scrolling,I am taking 40 records from the database.

```
                     var grid= new OnDemandGrid({

                store: jsonstore,
                columns: Layout,
                minRowsPerPage : 40,
                maxRowsPerPage : 40,
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                noDataMessage: "No results found."
            }, "grid");
```

On first time ,I am getting the response Header as
     Content-Range    items=0-39/132
.On further scrolling ,the response Header is 
                Content-Range   items=38-78/132 instead of 40-79/132.

Can someone tell me how to get the response as 40-79/132 , 80-119..etc..

Answer (score 1):

Add `queryRowsOverlap: 0` to the object you're passing to the grid constructor.

`queryRowsOverlap` defaults to 1, and is the reason the queries overlap.  This property is intended to counteract issues with dojo/store/Observable "dropping" items at page boundaries, though it isn't a perfect solution.